# When running laravel new command "Segmentation fault: 11" shows

Tags: laravel

I recently install valet but after completed when I run laravel new command it's given me this error: Segmentation fault: 11

Any solution, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try running :

```
sudo phpenmod xdebug
```

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried but said command not found!